# How do you find the available ranges in a Google sheet?

Tags: java, google-sheets-api

Using V4 of the Google Sheets API in Java. I'm trying to loop through the sheet reading off data, but am getting exceptions when I try to pull out a range that goes past the number of rows added to my sheet.

I can't find anything in their API that tell me what the last row and last column added to my sheet are.

Comment: Check the answer provided in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38607775/finding-last-written-row-in-google-spreadsheet-api).

Comment: ^ Doesn't work for me. If my sheet has 1,000 rows and I request range A1:B1005, I get an exception. I could parse the exception message to see the max number of rows in my sheet, but would prefer if there were an API option for this. Is there?

Comment: This worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37331756/google-sheets-api-v4-how-to-get-the-last-row-with-value